# Does Firefox sync browsing history?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, history

In the preferences in Firefox there is an option to sync the browsing history (and bookmarks, addons, prefs and so on) but how does it work?

I have three devices that are setup to sync and bookmarks seem to sync fine but history doesn't appear as expected - e.g., if I visit url A on machine 1, A is not marked as visited on machine 2.

Comment: Try asking on http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewforum.php?f=38